# I'm receiving a 419 page expired status code when trying to use requests. How do I successfully login?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm getting a 419 page expired status code when using requests on this site. I gathered the information for the headers and data by monitoring the network tab of the developer console. How can I use the Python requests module to successfully login?

```
import requests
url = 'https://rates.itgtrans.com/login'

headers = {
    'authority': 'rates.itgtrans.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'origin': 'https://rates.itgtrans.com',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://rates.itgtrans.com/login',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkEzbi9JQkVwbWloZTM1UVdSdVJtK0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM1pxQVYxajhPcWdlZ1NlYlVMSUlyQzFISVpPNjNrMVB0UmNYMXZGa0crSmYycURoem1vR0FzRUMrNjB2bXFPbCs4U3ZyeGM4ZVNLZ1NjRGVmditUMldNUUNmYmVzeTY2WS85VC93a1c0M0JUMk1Jek00TTNLVnlPb2VVRXpiN0ciLCJtYWMiOiJkNjQyMTMwMGRmZmQ4YTg0ZTNhZDgzODQ5M2NiMmE2ODdlYjRlOTIyMWE5Yjg4YzEyMTBjNTI2ODQxY2YxMzNkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; draymaster_session=eyJpdiI6Im9vUDZabmlYSTY0a1lSNGdYZzZHT0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMGVVcSs2T3RheGhMeDNVVFJUQjRmb212TkoySVY5eWFjeVNHT1lGWE9sRHdtR3JTa0REZFhMTzNJeisyTjNOZ1hrQnNscWY0dXBheFFaRFhIdDAvUlFMOFdvTFdaOXBoejcwb2ZDNFNMdDZ6MUFxT2dHU3hlNVkxZmpiTnd2Z0QiLCJtYWMiOiIwN2RmZTc1ZDUzYzViYTgzYWU1MjFjNjIxZjYzMzY3MDE0YjI4MDhkMWMwMTVkYmYxYWM2MzQ0ODM1YzRkNDY1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D'
}

data = {
  '_token': 'o8jJ4tR3PHkuz5TR2kuoHwBAdHd5RczFx2rlul1C',
  'email': '****',
  'password': '****',
  'button': ''
}



with requests.Session() as s:
    cookies = s.cookies
    p = s.post(url='https://rates.itgtrans.com/login', data=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print(p)
```

Comment: if you use `Session()` then you don't have to set manually `cookies` because `Session()` should do it automatically. But there is better if you first GET main page to get fresh cookies from server. Some cookies are valid only short time and you have to get fresh values from server. The same can be with `_token` - server may keep it in database for short time and check in database if it still valid.

Comment: I just checked and verified that the cookies and token for the GET is the same as the POST. So it must be something else.

Comment: did you check `p.text` ? It shows `Page Expired` and this can be problem because it may use expired `_token`. And when I run GET then I get HTML which always has different `_token` because page generate new token for every request and it can be valid only few minutes - all for security reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me all problem is that you always use the same `_token`.

Server for every user should generate new uniq token which is valid only few minutes - all for security reason (so hacker can't get it and use it after longer time)

BTW: went I run your code and get page with status `419` and display `p.text` then I see HTML with text `Page Expired` which can confirm that you use expired token.

---

You should always `GET` this page and search new token in HTML

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Xz0pJ0djGVnfaRMuXNDGMdBmZRbc55Ql2Q2CTPit"/>
```

and use this value in `POST`

---

I don't have account on this page but using fresh token from `<input name="_token">` I get status `200` instead of `419`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rates.itgtrans.com/login'

headers = {
    'authority': 'rates.itgtrans.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'origin': 'https://rates.itgtrans.com',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'referer': 'https://rates.itgtrans.com/login',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

data = {
  '_token': '-empty-',
  'email': '****',
  'password': '****',
  'button': ''
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    
    # --- first GET page ---

    response = s.get(url='https://rates.itgtrans.com/login', headers=headers)
    #print(response.text)

    # --- search fresh token in HTML ---
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    token = soup.find('input', {'name': "_token"})['value']
    print('token:', token)
    
    # --- run POST with new token ---

    data['_token'] = token
    
    response = s.post(url='https://rates.itgtrans.com/login', data=data, headers=headers)
    #print(response.text)
    print('status_code:', response.status_code)
```

**BTW:**

I get `200` even if I don't use `headers`.

Because code uses `Session` so I don't have to copy cookies from `GET` to `POST` because `Session` copies them automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Previously, I had looked at the token on the network tab after logging in. I thought it was the same. But your code worked perfectly so that was the problem after all.